# Azure edge deployments and config

Tags: configuration, azure-devops, azure-iot-hub

Is there a way to make use of the azure back-end to configure multiple edge devices with "version control".

Be able to set a value but also know what the value history looks like.

Comment: If you are asking about Azure IoT Edge can you add that tag? [azure-iot-edge].

Comment: On Azure IoT Edge you use modules that are containerized, and like any container you can use different tags for different versions. You can also leverage the [device twin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins) concept which use [Device twin metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#device-twin-metadata) to maintain timestamp of the last update for example.

Comment: I am already using the twin to do my configurations, but I am wondering if there is a way to see the history of the value eg. 
at 12:00 to '1' 
at 12:05 to '4'

....

Comment: Is this something that can help in your scenario? [Continuous integration and continuous deployment to Azure IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-ci-cd). I don't believe there is a built-in feature for IoTHub device twin to do that. You can ask a new feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in feature for IoTHub device twin to register the history of a property besides the last time updated. Please see how to achieve CI/CD here: [Continuous integration and continuous deployment to Azure IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-ci-cd)

Comment: I need to use this at scale. 1000+ edge devices each with a different config file.   I am creating a custom solution that makes use of the twin for each module. I am already using CI and it works for development. Module configuration seems like its is not well covered in existing solutions.